# How to fetch mysql COUNT Query value in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, count, laravel-blade

I have a Query in laravel 4 query builder which calculates a `count()`. it has a result as I dump its data. but I can't get its integer value.

here is my Query:

```
$data['provinces'] = DB::Table('doctors')
                        ->join('provinces', 'doctors.province_id', '=', 'provinces.id')
                        ->select('doctors.province_id','provinces.name as name',DB::raw("COUNT('doctors.province_id')"))
                        ->whereIn('doctors.id', $ids)
                        ->groupBy('doctors.province_id')
                        ->get();
```

here is my code in `blade` :

```
@foreach($data['provinces'] as $province)
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">{{$province->toArray()["name"]}}<span class="badge">{{$province->toArray()["COUNT('doctors.province_id')"]}}</span></a>
@endforeach
```

and here is my `dd($province)` :

```
object(stdClass)#582 (3) {
  ["province_id"]=>
  int(8)
  ["name"]=>
  string(10) "ØªÙ‡Ø±Ø§Ù†"
  ["COUNT('doctors.province_id')"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

How to fetch data from `["COUNT('doctors.province_id')"]` in blade. Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already fetch the provinces.name as name - you can do the same for the count:

```
DB::raw("COUNT('doctors.province_id') as mycount")
```

Then, all you need to do to get it is `$province->mycount`.